# django tornado getting 403 error on start

Tags: django, tornado

Following a tutorial I have written a management command to start tornado and it looks like:

```
import signal
import time

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

from privatemessages.tornadoapp import application

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = '[port_number]'
    help = 'Starts the Tornado application for message handling.'

    def sig_handler(self, sig, frame):
        """Catch signal and init callback"""
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(self.shutdown)

    def shutdown(self):
        """Stop server and add callback to stop i/o loop"""
        self.http_server.stop()

        io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
        io_loop.add_timeout(time.time() + 2, io_loop.stop)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if len(args) == 1:
            try:
                port = int(args[0])
            except ValueError:
                raise CommandError('Invalid port number specified')
        else:
            port = 8888


        self.http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
        self.http_server.listen(port, address="127.0.0.1")


        # Init signals handler
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.sig_handler)

        # This will also catch KeyboardInterrupt exception
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.sig_handler)
        print "start"

        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
        print "end"
```

Here I when I run this management command I get tornado `tornado.access:403 GET /2/ (127.0.0.1) 1.92ms` error

For test purpose I have printed "start" and "end". I guess when this command is executed successfully "end" should be printed.

Here only "start" is printed not "end". I guess there is something error on `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()` but I dont know what it is.

Can anyone guide me what is wrong in here ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put `self.http_server.start()` before starting the ioloop.

```
...
self.http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
self.http_server.listen(port, address="127.0.0.1")
self.http_server.start()
...
```

Update

Along with the httpserver start missing, are you using [this library](https://github.com/geraldoandradee/chat-2)?

Your management command is exactly [this one](https://github.com/geraldoandradee/chat-2/blob/master/privatemessages/management/commands/starttornadoapp.py)

Their tutorial is in russian and honestly, I don't read russian.

Update2:

What is see in their code, is that the url `/(?P<thread_id>\d+)/` is a websocket handler:

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r'/(?P<thread_id>\d+)/', MessagesHandler),
])
```

...

```
class MessagesHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
...
```

But the error you posted seems like something tried to access it in http via GET.
Honestly, without a debugger and the same environment, I can't figure out the issue.

Comment: I am getting the same error though I added self.http_server.start()

Comment: i believe I need to see more what is done in privatemessages.tornadoapp

Is it: https://github.com/geraldoandradee/chat-2/blob/master/privatemessages/tornadoapp.py ?

Comment: yup it is ... but tornado app is not started and message is not send on realtime